# replace file content during builidng war (maven2)

Tags: java, maven, build

How can I replace the content of a file just before maven-war-plugin uses it to build a war?

the point is:

- in tomcat started within eclipse and mvn tomcat:run i want to use development configuration. it should be on the classpath (e.g. in resource folder). so the file should be there in all phases up to test, but not during package phase
- on bamboo, uat, prod server i want this configuration to be removed. it will be provided from classpath
- but i don't want to remove the file. we use shared servers so anyone can put file with same name on classpath (by accident e.g. application.properties). so i want this file to be inside war (so spring will not look for it outside of war) but it should be empty.
- i don't want to use profiles because i want to have same package working on all environments

so the question is: how can i replace file's content during (or just before) building war

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please post an excerpt from file and the result you want. Sounds like it is a job for maven-resources plugin.

Comment: I solve these type problem with script. I hope there is a better solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found [maven replacer plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) it easily allows change file content

Answer (score 3):

I will give you a completely different answer here that will make it possible to have two different files with their own configuration that is then filtered to a single file.

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        ├── webapp
        |   └── WEB-INF
        |       └── web.xml
        ├── filters
        |   ├── dev.properties
        |   └── prod.properties
        └── resources
            ├── application.properties
            └── other.properties
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q13045684</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>dev-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>application.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>src/main/filters/dev.properties</filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prod-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>application.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>src/main/filters/prod.properties</filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

`src/main/filters/dev.properties`

```
someProperty = foo
someOtherProperty = bar
```

---

`src/main/filters/prod.properties`

```
someProperty =
someOtherProperty =
```

---

`src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
someProperty = ${someProperty}
someOtherProperty = ${someOtherProperty}
```

---

This will give you three files to work with. The output will only have the `application.properties`.

Comment: nice. i didn't think about it. it will produce 1 more level of indirection (as i need the production configuration to be read from classpath outside of war) but +1 for the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can elaborate a little with the [`maven-resources-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) to accomplish this.

First of all you will have to put your special file in one directory in the `src/main/resources` folder.

Then you place an empty file under another folder in the `src/main/resources` folder.

This is just an example:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        ├── webapp
        |   └── WEB-INF
        |       └── web.xml
        └── resources
            ├── prod
            |   └── application.properties
            └── dev
                └── application.properties
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q13045684</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>dev-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/dev</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prod-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/prod</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>dev/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>prod/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

With this configuration you will get different files in the `target/classes` folder depending on what goal you use.

```
mvn test
```

Will put the `src/main/resources/dev/application.properties` file in the `target/classes`.

```
mvn package
```

Will put the `src/main/resources/prod/application.properties` file in the `target/classes`.

Any other resources under `src/main/resources` will be copied and/or filtered as usual.

Comment: yes, i also thought about this but it's also annoying when in eclipse you are opening resource by name and instead of one file you see two. and you have to think which one is the real one

Comment: @piotrek Well according to your spec one file is going to be empty, right?

Comment: yes. but when you type 'appl' and eclipse shows you window with two files then you have to read the paths, select the proper one. instead of just hit enter. that's why i don't want them have same name

Answer (score 0):

Try the

```
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/
```

But its an anti-pattern. Better you use context-params and jndi-resources from the AppServer.

Comment: i though about jndi and environment variables but it's a pain in the ass. we want project to work on tomcat started inside eclipse, on mvn tomcat:run and also on production server. and without any tedious, repeating configuration of dev's environment